# CTAS , Syntax Error

Tags: sqlite, syntax-error

i have a problem with a query on an SQLite3 database

the query is this:

```
CREATE TABLE new_test AS (SELECT column1,column2 FROM test1)
```

or this:

```
CREATE TABLE 'new_test' AS (SELECT 'column1','column2' FROM test1)
```

The error is this:

```
near "(": syntax error
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As shown in [the documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtable.html), there are no parentheses around the SELECT statement:

```
CREATE TABLE new_test AS SELECT column1, column2 FROM test1
```